# How to monitor software installation in AD DS?

Tags: active-directory, monitoring

I'm trying to choose software for monitoring installed software in Active Directory Domain.
I thought to use SCCM services, but found it too complicated.
Maybe did anybody use a suitable solutions for this task?

Comment: Hi, what version of Windows Server are you using? what OS do your clients run?

Comment: Servers from 2008R2 to 2012, clients mostly windows 7

Comment: I am not putting this an as answer as I don't know enough about the tool or whether it will gather the information that you need. Have you considerd using Applocker in Audit mode? this will show you what applications are being run on your systems. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791796(v=ws.10).aspx it might not get all the information you want but it looks easy to configure and might be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform software monitoring using [10-Stike Network Inventory Explorer](http://www.10-strike.com/networkinventoryexplorer/).
The program scans your computers automatically, and when it scans the PCs again, it compares the results and finds changes, so you can track all the changes. **AD is supported.**

For data collecting you can use WMI ([Windows Management Instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)) or logon-script.

All the changes found during the last consecutive aggregation of data can be found in the program log.  Besides, you can view not only software but also hardware data and its changes. Filters are adjusted.

In addition program has other features:

- You can be notified on the software changes via a screen message, sound, or e-mail.
- Generate a lot of hardware and software reports
- The Pro version of the program allows performing more detailed SAM processes. It has got a built-in Software Library containing more than 100 000 software titles split by categories, with defined license types, and prices.

Hope, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just monitoring and nothing else (not deploying or block installations), I suggest to deploy OCS Inventory Server, and installing the agent in your clients.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the **Inventory** feature of Pandora FMS Enterprise. Apart from their tremendous server monitoring capabilities (http://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/server-monitoring), they can collect Inventory information of Software, Patches, Services, Hardware and basically, what ever you want!